Wix Rest API throws 403 Forbidden
I've tried simple Wix Rest API requests such as
 curl -X GET \
 https://www.wixapis.com/apps/v1/instance \
 -H 'Authorization: <AUTH>'

I tried doing it using Windows Terminal, Python requests library and Postman and all of them have thrown 403 Error.
Wix Docs suggest, that there is a problem with the Permission Scopes (https://dev.wix.com/docs/build-apps/develop-your-app/api-integrations/rest). However, it doesn't specify how to change a permission scope for the REST API in the dashboard. Moreover, my Dashboard clearly says, that all the permissions should be intact.

I would be grateful, if you help to resolve this issue.

What are you using for authorization?

@Sam there is a generated API Key, that I paste into requests' Authorisation header.

So, the problem was in the absence of wix-site-id header in a request. For some reason, Wix Docs do a really poor job of explaining the necessity of this. If you use only API Key as a Header, you essentially send a request to your account itself. And even that won't work in a case when you need to make an account-level request, you need to additionally employ your wix-accound-id.
